# How to push the layout up once the ad banner is shown?

Tags: android, admob, screen-size, adjustment

I have a relative layout which contains:

1. adView which is aligned at the parent layout's bottom. another
2. Relative layout containing the app view like buttons and others.

As known, ads are sometimes not available or the wifi is off hence it is  not wise to leave the adview space empty while the ad is not available. Hence, I want the inside relative layout to automatically shift up when the ad banner appears.
How may I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did to solve this problem was embed the adview inside an otherwise empty linearlayout, with the AdView defaulted to visibility:gone. I added an AdListener to the AdView and set the visibility to "visible" in the onAdLoaded method in the AdListener.

```
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ad_wrapper"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

and then

```
    adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
            adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: That's exactly how I managed to do it a few days after posting this question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest embedding your RelativeLayout inside a LinearLayout, set the LinearLayout orientation to vertical, like :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Your Ad view -->

    <RelativeLayout ....>
           <!-- items -->
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

if you set within your code the adview to View.GONE, the placement in the LinearLayout will be displaced, and the below content (RelativeLayout) will shift up.

Comment: I tried but the problem persists. Nothing changes. The ad keeps maintaining some space even when it is not shown.

Comment: Please Gist your layout XML.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you say "it is not wise to leave the adview space empty while the ad is not available"?

There is absolutely nothing wrong with doing that and leaving it visible can often make your layout easier to manage.

But if you **really** want to hide it when no ad is available then use the AdListener method to set the visibility on the AdView.